# C# Import X509Certificate network password is not correct only on Win 2016 LTSB

Tags: c#, .net, windows, certificate, x509certificate2

**Starting situation:**

I have a certificate (RSA-SHA1) with the corresponding password. I have the certificate and the password as a string. The password has 32 characters.

**My Code (.NET Framework 4.8 and 4.7.2):**

```
string cert = "mycert";
string pw = "mypassword";

var convertedCert = Convert.FromBase64String(cert);

var certs = new X509Certificate2();
certs.Import(convertedCert , pw, X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlag
```

**My Problem:**

On my own computer (Windows 10 Pro 19044), importing is possible without any problems. I don't get any error message or anything else. On other computers (Windows 2016 Enterprise LTSB Build 14393 & Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSB release 1607) I always get the following exception:s.UserKeySet);

> ERROR: MyTestApp.ImportCertificate() - failed with exception:
> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The specified
> network password is not correct.
>
> bei
> System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection.LoadStoreFromBlob(Byte[]
> rawData, String password, UInt32 dwFlags, Boolean
> persistKeyContainers)    bei
> System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection.Import(Byte[]
> rawData, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)

**What I have already tried/ What we can exclude:**

- Older Win 10 versions cannot handle SHA-256 - I use SHA-1
- My password is not longer than 32 characters - I have read that longer passwords
  do not work in some cases
- The password is 100% correct because it works on my machine
- Starting as admin on the LTSB did not help - To avoid access problems
- Changing the KeyStorageFlag to MachineKeySet did not help - To ensure that access to the UserKeySet does not work
- C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA exists on LTSB
- But C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys exists on LTSB
- I don't know if newer LTSB Windows Versions are affected too

These are all possible problems that could arise according to the internet and Stackoverflow research.
However, I was able to verify that these errors do not apply to me.

I also debugged into the X509Certificate2 and found the following: I get as far as the LoadStoreFromBlob() point. In LoadStoreFromBlob the property hCertStore.IsInvalid is true and I get the exception

Here also the code of LoadStoreFromBlob():

```
private unsafe static System.Security.Cryptography.SafeCertStoreHandle LoadStoreFromBlob(byte[] rawData, string password, uint dwFlags, bool persistKeyContainers)
{
    uint num = 0u;
    System.Security.Cryptography.SafeCertStoreHandle phCertStore = System.Security.Cryptography.SafeCertStoreHandle.InvalidHandle;
    if (!CAPI.CryptQueryObject(2u, rawData, 5938u, 14u, 0u, IntPtr.Zero, new IntPtr(&num), IntPtr.Zero, ref phCertStore, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero))
    {
        throw new CryptographicException(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    }

    if (num == 12)
    {
        phCertStore.Dispose();
        phCertStore = CAPI.PFXImportCertStore(2u, rawData, password, dwFlags, persistKeyContainers);
    }

    if (phCertStore == null || phCertStore.IsInvalid)
    {
        throw new CryptographicException(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    }

    return phCertStore;
}
```

So I suspect it's related to the LTSB but unfortunately I don't know what else to check.

**Updates**

I have converted the certificate into a pfx file.
After the conversion, I tried to import it using the "Certificate Import Wizard".
Here I also get the error message:
"The password you entered is incorrect".
On my computer it works again - only Windows 10 LTSB 2016 is affected.

Comment: I think you have a Group Policy issue.  The error says "The specified network password is not correct.".  Talk to your Network people and see if they can help.  The encryption mode of the certificate is failing.  Older version of Windows may not support all encryption modes.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/tls/tls-schannel-ssp-changes-in-windows-10-and-windows-server

Comment: It may well be a GPO problem, but I can't find any settings to change this. And I didn't get much further with a Google search.

Comment: See following : https://www.techinpost.com/the-specified-network-password-is-not-correct/

Comment: @jdweng The URL you sent is for problems that occur when connecting to a network drive.

Comment: A network drive is a shared drive on a machine (could be linux or windows).  To access the driver you need the same network credentials that you would need to connect to a remote machine using HTTP credentials.  At work with have a Driver Server which is a windows machine configured with lots of Tera Drives.

Comment: Yes, but this is about the import of certificates. Unfortunately, I have not yet fully got the connection?

Comment: What is the certificate being used for?  It the certificate being used for TLS which is done before the connection is made or for credentials?  If it is for credentials, than the connection has to complete before the credentials are checked.  The certificate would be sent and then the login would be rejected.  A connection always has to complete if data is sent.  The connection is the low level transport layer.  Validation is done at a higher level. So if connection does not complete than it is probably the TLS that is failing.  There also may be a proxy involved.  Connection to proxy works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .p12 file probably cannot be imported into Windows 2016 using the built-in Windows 2016 tools. To check that: "For each of your PKCS #12 files, you could try the following: issue the command certutil -asn | findstr /i "pb aes des sha" (replacing "" with the name of the PKCS #12 file).

If the output starts like:

| | | | | ; 1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.3 szOID_PKCS_12_pbeWithSHA1And3KeyTripleDES

then it should be possible to import the PKCS #12 file into Windows 2016.

If the output starts like:

| | | | | ; 1.2.840.113549.1.5.13 szOID_PKCS_5_PBES2 | | | | | | ; 1.2.840.113549.1.5.12 szOID_PKCS_5_PBKDF2 | | | | | ; 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.42 aes256

or similar, then the PKCS #12 file probably cannot be imported into Windows 2016 using the built-in Windows 2016 tools. You will have to recreate the PKCS #12 file using TripleDES and SHA1." - see thread: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/518605/importing-a-pkcs12-to-windows-server-2016.html

Converting an Incompatible PKCS#12 Format File to a Compatible PKCS#12: https://kb.globalscape.com/Knowledgebase/11040/Converting-an-Incompatible-PKCS12-Format-File-to-a-Compatible-PKCS12

Comment: I don't get any of them back. Instead I get: ; 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1 sha256 (sha256NoSign).Does it mean that is a SHA256 encrypted pfx certificate? Because Win10 <= 1703 doesn't support importing SHA256 encrypted pfx certificates.

Comment: yes, you should use openssl.exe to convert it to a Windows 2016 accepted format

Comment: Thank you ! Is there a way to convert it with .net resources - do you have an idea?

Comment: no, not to my knowledge